# TDD : Breaks all the existing test cases while refactoring the code

Tags: c#, tdd

I have started following TDD in my project. But ever since I started, even after reading some articles, I am confused since the development has slowed down. Whenever I refactor my code, I need to change the existing test cases I have written before because otherwise they will start failing.

The following is an example of a class I recently refactored:

```cs
public class SalaryManager
{
    public string CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage(int daysWorked, int monthlySalary)
    {
        int salary = 0, tempSalary = 0;
        if (daysWorked < 15)
        {
            tempSalary = (monthlySalary / 30) * daysWorked;
            salary = tempSalary - 0.1 * tempSalary;
        }
        else
        {
            tempSalary = (monthlySalary / 30) * daysWorked;
            salary = tempSalary + 0.1 * tempSalary;
        }

        string message = string.Empty;
        if (salary < (monthlySalary / 30))
        {
            message = "Salary cannot be generated. It should be greater than 1 day salary.";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Salary generated as per the policy.";
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

But now I am doing lot of things in one method, so to follow the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP), I refactored it to something like below:

```cs
public class SalaryManager
{
    private readonly ISalaryCalculator _salaryCalculator;        
    private readonly SalaryMessageFormatter _messageFormatter;
    public SalaryManager(ISalaryCalculator salaryCalculator, ISalaryMessageFormatter _messageFormatter){
        _salaryCalculator = salaryCalculator;
        _messageFormatter = messageFormatter;
    }

    public string CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage(int daysWorked, int monthlySalary)
    {
        int salary = _salaryCalculator.CalculateSalary(daysWorked, monthlySalary);
        string message = _messageFormatter.FormatSalaryCalculationMessage(salary);

        return message;
    }
}

public class SalaryCalculator
{
    public int CalculateSalary(int daysWorked, int monthlySalary)
    {
        int salary = 0, tempSalary = 0;
        if (daysWorked < 15)
        {
            tempSalary = (monthlySalary / 30) * daysWorked;
            salary = tempSalary - 0.1 * tempSalary;
        }
        else
        {
            tempSalary = (monthlySalary / 30) * daysWorked;
            salary = tempSalary + 0.1 * tempSalary;
        }
        return salary;
    }
}

public class SalaryMessageFormatter
{
    public string FormatSalaryCalculationMessage(int salary)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        if (salary < (monthlySalary / 30))
        {
            message = "Salary cannot be generated. It should be greater than 1 day salary.";
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Salary generated as per the policy.";
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

This may not be the greatest of examples. But the main point is that as soon as I did the refactoring, my existing test cases which I wrote for the `SalaryManager` started failing and I had to fix them using mocking.

This happens all the time in read time scenarios, and the time of development increases with it. I am not sure if I am doing TDD in the right way. Please help me to understand.

Comment: What is an example of a test that would pass for the first case and fail for the second case? The refactoring looks like it should be ok on a conceptual level, although the code doesn't actually compile.

Comment: `CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage` takes two integers and return a `string`. Have no other dependencies - so your tests should be ok with any refactoring. Only possible change I see - add new arguments for constructor of `SalaryManager`. You don't even need to write mock - pass actual implementations and tests will works.

Comment: @Fabio: I have changed the code to introduce the dependencies and make my question more understandable. Now can you please help me with three questions 1) As soon as I move the code to SalaryCalculator, I need to do mocking right? 2) After mocking, salary calculation test cases will not be relevant on salary manager since the logic does not exists in SalaryManager class anymore 3) Do I need to move test cases since Salary calculation tests becomes more relevant to SalaryCalculator?

Comment: 2. Do not mock `SalarayCalculator` - pass it to the `SalaryManager` in the tests. Mock only dependencies which makes your tests slow(reading/writing files, databases, webservices or other external resources). 3. - without mocking your tests remain same and you will be free to refactor `SalaryManager` class without touching tests.

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever I refactor my code, I need to change the existing test cases I have written before because they will start failing.

That's certainly an indication that something is going wrong.  The popular definition of refactoring goes something like [this](https://refactoring.com/)

> REFACTORING is a disciplined technique for restructuring an existing body of code, altering its internal structure without changing its external behavior.

Part of the point of having the unit tests, is that the unit tests are evaluating the external behavior of your implementation.  A unit test that fails indicates that an implementation change has changed the externally observable behavior in some way.

In this particular case, it looks like you changed your API - specifically, you removed the default constructor that had been part of the API for creating instances of `SalaryManager`; that's not a "refactoring", it's a backwards breaking change.

There's nothing wrong with introducing new collaborators while refactoring, but you should do so in a way that doesn't break the current API contract.

```
public class SalaryManager
{
    public SalaryManager(ISalaryCalculator salaryCalculator, ISalaryMessageFormatter _messageFormatter){
        _salaryCalculator = salaryCalculator;
        _messageFormatter = messageFormatter;
    }

    public SalaryManager() {
        this(new SalaryCalculator(), new SalaryMessageFormatter())
    }
```

where `SalaryCalculator` and `SalaryMessageFormatter` should be implementations that produce the same observable behavior that you had originally.

Of course, there are occasions where we need to introduce a backwards breaking change.  However, "Refactoring" isn't the appropriate tool for that case.  In many cases, you can achieve the result you want in several phases: first extending your API with new tests (refactoring to remove duplication with the existing implementation), then removing the tests that evaluate the old API, and finally removing the old API.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when refactoring changes responsibilities of existing units especially by introducing new units or removing existing units.

You can do this in TDD style but you need to:

1. do small steps (this rules out changes that extracts both classes simultaneously)
2. refactor (this includes refactoring test code as well!)

### Starting point

In your case you have (I use more abstract python-like syntax to have less boilerplate, this problem is language independent):

```
class SalaryManager:
    def CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage(daysWorked, monthlySalary):
      // code that has two responsibilities calculation and formatting
```

You have test class for it. If you don't have tests you need to create these tests first (here you may find [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) really helpful) or in many cases together with some refactoring to be able to refactor you code even more (refactoring is changing code structure without changing its functionality so you need to have test to be sure you don't change the functionality).

```
class SalaryManagerTest:
    def test_calculation_1():
      // some test for calculation

    def test_calculation_2():
      // another test for calculation

    def test_formatting_1():
      // some test for formatting

    def test_formatting_2():
      // another test for calculation

    def test_that_checks_both_formatting_and_calculation():
      // some test for both
```

### Extracting calculation to a class

Now let's you what to extract calculation responsibility to a class.

You can do it right away without changing API of the `SalaryManager`. In classical TDD you do it in small steps and run tests after each step, something like this:

1. extract calculation to a function (say `calculateSalary`) of `SalaryManager`
2. create empty `SalaryCalculator` class
3. create instance of `SalaryCalculator` class in `SalaryManager`
4. move  `calculateSalary` to `SalaryCalculator`

Sometimes (if `SalaryCalculator` is simple and its interactions with `SalaryManager` are simple) you can stop here and do not change tests at all. So tests for calculation will still be part of `SalaryManager`. With the increasing of complexity of `SalaryCalculator` it will be hard/impractical to test it via `SalaryManager` so you will need to do the second step - refactor tests as well.

### Refactor tests

I would do something like this:

1. split `SalaryManagerTest` into `SalaryManagerTest` and `SalaryCalculatorTest` basically by copying the class
2. remove `test_calculation_1` and `test_calculation_1` from `SalaryManagerTest`
3. leave only `test_calculation_1` and `test_calculation_1` in `SalaryCalculatorTest`

Now tests in `SalaryCalculatorTest` test functionality for calculation but do it via `SalaryManager`. You need to do two things:

1. make sure you have integration test that checks that calculation happens at all
2. change `SalaryCalculatorTest` so that it does not use `SalaryManager`

### Integration test

1. If you don't have such test already (`test_that_checks_both_formatting_and_calculation` may be such a test) create a test that does some simple usecase when calculation is involved from `SalaryManager`
2. You may want to move that test to `SalaryManagerIntegrationTest` if you wish

### Make SalaryCalculatorTest use SalaryCalculator

Tests in `SalaryCalculatorTest` are all about calculation so even if they deal with manager their essence and important part is providing input to calculation and then check the result of it.

Now our goal is to refactor the tests in a way so that it is easy to switch manager for calculator.

The test for calculation may look like this:

```
class SalaryCalculatorTest:

    def test_short_period_calculation(self):
       manager = new SalaryManager()
       DAYS_WORKED = 1
       result = manager.CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage(DAYS_WORKED, SALARY)
       assertEquals(result.contains('Salary cannot be generated'), True)
```

There are three things here:

1. preparation of the objects for tests
2. invocation of the action
3. check of the outcome

Note that such test will check outcome of the calculation in some way. It may be confusing and fragile but it will do it somehow. As there should be some externally visible way to distinguish how calculation ended. Otherwise (if it does not have any visible effect) such calculation does not make sense.

You can refactor like this:

1. extract creation of the `manager` to a function `createCalculator` (it is ok to call it this way as the object that is created from the test perspective is the calculator)
2. rename `manager` -> `sut` (system under test)
3. extract `manager.CalculateSalaryAndSendMessage` invocation into a function `calculate(calculator, days, salary)
4. extract the check into a function `assertPeriodIsTooShort(result)`

Now the test has no direct reference to manager, it reflects the essence of what is tested.

Such refactoring should be done with all tests and functions in this test class. Don't miss the opportunity to reuse some of them like `createCalculator`.

Now you can change what object is created in `createCalculator` and what object is expected (and how the check is done) in `assertPeriodIsTooShort`. The trick here is to still control the size of that change. If it is too big (that is you can't make test green after the change in couple minutes in classical TDD) you may need to create a copy of the `createCalculator` and `assert...` and use them in one test only first but then gradually replace old with one in other tests.

Comment: Thanks Roman for your effort in explaining it TDD way.  I think I do it in the similar way how you have explained. The only thing I feel is Unit tests are too brittle in nature and refactoring also needs Test refactoring in complex cases which makes it more time consuming. I am handling a team right now and different people handle differently, making it uniform practice to be followed.

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is due to a general misunderstanding about unit testing. At some point people started to spread the myth that a unit is something like a single class or even a single method. This was fuelled by the relevant literature, articles and blog posts which showed how it is done with very small isolated classes. It was overlooked that the reason for that was the fact that you can not present a development process in a book or article with a real life application, as it would be by far too big for the format.

It is true, that a unit test needs to be isolated. This does not mean that the "unit" needs to be completely isolated. The test itself needs to be isolated from other tests. This means that tests should not depend on each other and it should be possible to run them separately or even in parallel.

The relevant unit for a unit test should be a use case. A use case is a feature of your application. In a blog engine "create blog post" is a use case. In a hotel reservation system "find free room" is a use case. Usually you will find the entry point for these in so called application services. That's the granularity you should aim for. Mock away ugly external dependencies like databases, file systems and external services. If you refactor the inner structure of your application the test will not break, because you do not change the behavior of the use case. Want to split or merge classes in your domain? The use case will be stable. Change how your domain objects interact with each other. The tests stay green.